# How do I listen to an Azure http trigger function on a desktop application?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, listener, webhooks

I have created an Azure function that process the payload of a webhook from another service. I would like to listen to that Azure function from a desktop application running .NET framework 4.7 so I catch the event whenever the function fires after receiving the webhook notification. What's the best way to achieve that?

Comment: The Azure function could post a message to a bus or queue that your desktop app is monitoring as a client. There isn't a "best" way, it depends on many factors

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I shoudl have been more specific. I am basically receiving webhook notifications of payment response message from the payment processing service after a payment is initiated from app to terminal device. So essentially the app will need to be listeniing to http trigger all the time while running

Comment: There is no way to listen, the trigger does not emit anything by default, it will have to intentionally perform some kind of action.

Comment: understood, so I will need to have the Azure function post a message to a queue and have my desktop app monitor it